# Transit at Munich Airport (From Hong Kong to Dublin)

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports, lufthansa

I will travel from Hong Kong to Dublin via Munich. The two legs are both operated by Lufthansa (LH731 and LH2514). The booking came with one e-ticket number. I have confirmed with Lufthansa that my baggage will be checked through to Dublin. And I have the following questions:

- Will I go through immigration and customs at Munich?
- Will I have to leave the transit area of Munich Airport? (I ask this because if I have to leave the transit area, I have to apply for a visitor visa as I hold a Chinese (PRC) Passport.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munich is one of the better airports in the world to transit through.

You will NOT need to go through immigration/customs in Munich, and you will not be required to exit the transit area.  Chinese citizens do not require a visa, as long as you have an onward ticket departing within 24 hours.

Comment: So will LH counter in Hong Kong Airport issue an onward boarding pass to me?

Comment: Since you are booked on a single ticket, they will likely issue you with both boarding passes when you check-in in Hong Hong. In the event that they don't, they can get you one at a transfer desk or the gate in Munich. In some cases it might even be possible to get a boarding pass on your phone, but it depends on your itinerary.

Comment: Also wonder if there's no immigration for transit passengers in Munich Airport then how do they know if the citizens are transit visa exempted? Say citizens from India, they need transit visa to transit in Munich.

Comment: Checks are carried out electronically when you check-in for the initial flight.  They will also sometimes have border staff checking passports as you exit the plane, although this is not actually immigration as such.